# why two resource file in class library create two dlls in debug folder

Tags: c#, dll, resources, resx

I add two resource files to support English and French languages when I build class library in visual studio in debug folder create two dlls something like this:

```
/debug/commonlibrary.dll
/debug/fr/commonlibrary.dll
```

Is there any way to have one dll for two resources?
my default resource file has interanl access modifier and french resource has no code generation.

Comment: That's how it works - the runtime will probe for the appropriate DLL depending on current locale. Also, you only need to have the code generation for the primary resource file.